# Migrar etiqueta de [scope] a [alcance]

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Actualmente hay 33 preguntas con la etiqueta [scope](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scope) y una etiqueta nueva sobre [alcance](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alcance).

Creo que seria prudente migrar el uso de la primer etiqueta a la segunda y registrar un alias para las personas que intenten seguir usando [scope](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scope).

Comment: debería ser al revés... el termino en programación es scope, alcance es un alias en español (traduccion) ...

Comment: Yo estoy de acuerdo con francisco... scope es un termino de los lenguajes de programacion... alcance (aunque es la traduccion) es dudoso... pero esperemos a ver que dice mas gente...

Comment: Los principiantes de programación y/o que no sepan inglés preguntaran por "scope" y este es el término correcto para hablar sobre la accesibilidad de una variable/dato

Comment: Podríamos crear un sinónimo de "alcance" a "scope".

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro no por que alcance en términos de Desarrollo tiene un significado alejado a scope ... una etiqueta sinónimo puede ser [niveles-de-acceso-de-variable]

Answer (score 4):

En mi opinión esas etiquetas son muy generales. Las preguntas marcadas con esta etiqueta no tienen mayor relación entre ellas.

Mi sugerencia es quemarlas ambas!

Answer (score 0):

No Estoy de acuerdo en que deban ser sinónimo.

La mayoría de lenguajes/desarrollo se refieren al nivel de acceso de una variable con la palabra [scope] tanto documental como parte del código declarativo.

Cuando en un desarrollo implementamos la palabra técnica [alcance] nos referimos a los objetivos y metas de un software, o código claramente esto debería ser la palabra ***propósito*** o ***Finalidad*** pero puede ser informal su uso... y no al niveles de acceso de una variable en un lenguaje determinado:

**Ejemplo:**
*el Script Actual no tiene el **alcance** deseado; se debe refactorizar y agregarle los escenario adicionales para cumplir con los objetivos.*

por otro lado si vemos la actual descripción:

***versión en español:***

> El alcance es un contexto envolvente donde se asocian valores y
> expresiones. El operador de resolución de alcance ayuda a identificar
> y especificar el contexto al que se refiere a un identificador,
> particularmente al especificar un espacio de nombres.

***version del sitio en ingles (traducción):***

> El alcance es un contexto envolvente donde se asocian valores y
> expresiones. Utilice esta etiqueta para preguntas sobre diferentes
> tipos de alcance, así como para preguntas en las que el alcance puede
> no estar claro.

podemos observar que la del sitio en ingles tiene 16,514 preguntas relacionadas (hasta hoy) y que su definición es mucho mas abierta y general.

me parece que la etiqueta es funcional solo que en el sitio en español no se le ha dado tanta relevancia, ya que se suelen usar otras etiquetas como [variable], [variables-globales].

incluso si se considera usar como sinónimo o alias, la principal debe ser [scope], la otra es una españolización/traducción de un termino nativamente ingles.